# jQuery - HighCharts Labels outside Series (Bar Chart)

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            backgroundColor: null,
            width: 360
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
            style: {
                display: 'none'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null,
            style: {
                display: 'none'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4', 'Cat 5', 'Cat 6', 'Cat 7', 'Cat 8', 'Cat 9', 'Cat 10'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },  
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    crop: false,
                    enabled: true,
                    y: -2,
                    inside: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            name: '',
            color: '#CCC',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 9.4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9.5]

    }]
});
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNrW2/1/

I can't seem to get the labels of the series' data to always appear on the RIGHT of the bar.
I have gone through all the API and I can't seem to find an option to stop the text from getting moved into the bar.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've missed one option in the API called `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow)):

> overflow: String
>
> How to handle data labels that flow outside the plot area. The default is `justify`, which aligns them inside the plot area. For columns and bars, this means it will be moved inside the bar. To display data labels outside the plot area, set `crop` to `false` and `overflow` to `"none"`. Defaults to justify.

In other words, you need to combine crop and overflow, like this ([updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNrW2/2/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            crop: false,
            overflow: 'none'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot Ondkloss! I didn't expect overflow to be the fix, and that API is so huge, so many options. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can I ask you one last question, if a value is 10, it will only display the first digit, is there a way to move the value to the left a bit if its 10?

Comment: By changing the `yAxis{max:11..` it works http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/uNrW2/3/